# Unity3d NavMesh странно работает, не могу понять в чем причина

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: Первая волна зеленых идет правильно (к первому вейпоинту), а вот после удлинения тоннеля, вторая волна зеленых почему то теряют первый вейпоинт и сразу идут ко второму. (Причем почему то каким то обходным путем идут)]

Первая волна зеленых идет правильно (к первому вейпоинту), а вот после удлинения тоннеля, вторая волна зеленых почему то теряют первый вейпоинт и сразу идут ко второму. (Причем почему то каким то обходным путем идут)

Собственно два вопроса:
1) как починить первый вейпоинт
2) почему так странно идут ко второму вейпоинту

Вот код врага для перебора вейпоинтов

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(NavMeshAgent))]
public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] public Transform[] points;
    [SerializeField] private int destPoint = 0;
    private NavMeshAgent agent;

    void Start()
    {        
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        agent.autoBraking = false;
        agent.destination = points[destPoint].position;
    }

    void GotoNextPoint()
    {        
        if(destPoint != points.Length)
        {
            agent.destination = points[destPoint].position;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(agent.remainingDistance < 0.5f)
        {
            destPoint++;
            GotoNextPoint();
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.DrawLine(gameObject.transform.position, points[destPoint].position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ок 1) я починил, оказало что агент не успевает полностью просчитать путь, поэтому agent.destination равен бесконечности, это тоже самое что 0 в юнити. Поэтому агенты сразу переключались на второй вейпоинт.
Но вот пункт 2) мне пока не удается решить. Почему то путь строиться не кратчайший, а так чтобы прочти меньшее кол-во отрезков пути, поэтому unity строит путь через вертекс NavMesh'a 

Нужна помощь ! )=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кароче решено, дело в том, что навМеш делает крупные тайлы (NavMeshBuildSettings.tileSize), но я никак не мог изменить его, так как использовал чужую наработку (https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/NavMeshComponents/tree/mast… mples/Scripts). Так вот оказалось, что бы рантаймовый навМеш поменять, надо не только в коде изменения сетки прописать, но и написать строчку  var defaultBuildSettings = **NavMesh.GetSettingsByID(0).overrideTileSize = true**; 
После этого я смог изменить размер тайла, и выбор неправильного пути прекратился.